# Consulta SQL Filtrar por condicniones

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas, where

Se tienen estas dos tablas en sql Server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que Sentencia podria utilizar para Recupere los nombres y departamentos de especialidad de todos los estudiantes que hayan obtenido la nota ‘A’ o ‘B’ en todos los cursos.

Hasta el momento intente esto :
`Select A.Nombre,A.Apellido,A.Especialidad`

`From Alumno AS A`

`join Informe_Calificaciones AS IC on A.Codigo_alumno = IC.Codigo_alumno`

`Where (Calificacion='A' or Calificacion='B')`

`group by A.Nombre,A.Apellido,A.Especialida`

Y me sale :

| Nombre | Apellido | Especialidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Smith | MATE |
| Mia | Brown | CS |

El problema es que Como hacer para que no me tire el alumno 17 que es John  por que el tuvo una C en una seccion

Comment: Muestra las consultas _como texto, con formato_ y muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Además, menciona qué gestor de base de datos estás utilizando y pon en el título qué problema _específico_ estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Una forma bastante sencilla es consultar por aquellos que no hayan tenido ninguna calificación distinta de `A` o `B`, para esto hay que ver cuales si tuvieron otra nota:

```
select distinct Codigo_alumno
       from Informe_Calificaciones 
       where Calificacion not in ('A', 'B')
```

Usando esto en una subconsulta podremos dar con aquellos que solo tuvieron `A` o `B`

```
Select A.Nombre,
       A.Apellido,
       A.Especialidad
       From Alumno A
       inner join Informe_Calificaciones IC 
             on A.Codigo_alumno = IC.Codigo_alumno
       where A.Codigo_alumno not in (select distinct Codigo_alumno
                                            from Informe_Calificaciones 
                                            where Calificacion not in ('A', 'B'))
       
       group by A.Nombre,
                A.Apellido,
                A.Especialida
```

Comentarios:

- El `inner join Informe_Calificaciones` es necesario, aunque no usemos estos datos, por si hay alumnos que directamente nunca tuvieron calificaciones, obviamente no los queremos en esta consulta
- Podríamos quitar la tabla de calificaciones agregando otra subconsulta para filtrar aquellos alumnos que si tuvieron calificaciones `A` o `B`

Lo que mencionaba en mi último comentario:

```
Select A.Nombre,
       A.Apellido,
       A.Especialidad
       From Alumno A
       where A.Codigo_alumno not in (select distinct Codigo_alumno
                                            from Informe_Calificaciones 
                                            where Calificacion not in ('A', 'B'))
              and A.Codigo_alumno not in (select distinct Codigo_alumno
                                            from Informe_Calificaciones 
                                            where Calificacion in ('A', 'B'))
```

Por último, otra forma sería "contar" por alumno las calificaciones de un tipo o de otro:

```
Select A.Nombre,
       A.Apellido,
       A.Especialidad
       From Alumno A
       inner join (select  Codigo_alumno,
                           sum(case when Calificacion in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) as AoB,
                           sum(case when Calificacion not in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) as NoAoB
                           from Informe_Calificaciones 
                           group by Codigo_alumno
                ) IC
                on A.Codigo_alumno = IC.Codigo_alumno
    where   IC.AoB > 0
            and IC.NoAoB = 0
```